# Eset antivirus 5 license vs ver 5?

Tags: anti-virus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

I have already purchased antivirus 4 (eset) .

Is this license valid to eset antivirus 5 ?

Do I need to purchase another antivirus ?

Comment: The fastest, and most accurate, way to get an answer to this question is to [contact Eset](http://www.eset.com/us/about/contact/) directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your version 4 license will transfer to version 5.